# How to enter multiple Android Client ID in mobile backend starter?

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints

I wish to connect my development and testing apks to the appspot backend.

On .appspot.com/admin/configure.jsp it appears that I can only enter one Android Client ID, and from the cloud backend credentials page, each apk needs to have a unique oauth2 ID. How can I connect different versions to the same backend?

Or must I create a new appspot instance?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to create a separate backend for testing, as some of your changes under test will need server changes as well.

To support multiple Android Client IDs in the same server code, you need to configure multiple client IDs on the @API annotation in endpoints API spec. Which you can do by giving comma separated values.

```
@Api(name = "api_name", version = "v1", clientIds = {ANDROID_CLIENT_ID1, ANDROID_CLIENT_ID2}
```

In the client, you have to pass only one client ID. You can pick one based on a switch or a config that decides whether to connect to the production instance or the test instance.